# How to fetch data value from quote_item_option table in cart page?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

How to fetch value of no_of_windows ?
I want to display custom field information in cart page? How to do that?

```
a:12:{s:4:"uenc";s:72:"aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguNS41OC9NYWdlbnRvMjE3L2luZGV4LnBocC9uZXR0aW5nLmh0bWw,";s:7:"product";s:4:"2115";s:28:"selected_configurable_option";s:0:"";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:15:"super_attribute";a:2:{i:162;s:3:"223";i:93;s:2:"49";}s:13:"no_of_windows";s:1:"2";s:7:"width_1";s:1:"1";s:8:"height_1";s:1:"2";s:7:"width_2";s:1:"1";s:8:"height_2";s:1:"3";s:11:"total_price";s:3:"100";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}
```

Comment: did you try with json_decode()?

Comment: actually I know this information I am getting from quote_item_option table but I dont know where to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a serialize data you can simple unserialize it

```
$str = a:12:{s:4:"uenc";s:72:"aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguNS41OC9NYWdlbnRvMjE3L2luZGV4LnBocC9uZXR0aW5nLmh0bWw,";s:7:"product";s:4:"2115";s:28:"selected_configurable_option";s:0:"";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:15:"super_attribute";a:2:{i:162;s:3:"223";i:93;s:2:"49";}s:13:"no_of_windows";s:1:"2";s:7:"width_1";s:1:"1";s:8:"height_1";s:1:"2";s:7:"width_2";s:1:"1";s:8:"height_2";s:1:"3";s:11:"total_price";s:3:"100";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}
$cartOptions = unserialize($str);
```

You will get result in array and you can display it by

```
$cartOptions['no_of_windows'];
```

Comment: ok, how to display label and  value of $cartOptions['no_of_windows'] in cart page?